# IOS ATT Apptrackingtransparency guidelines

Tags: ios, itunes

I reaching out in hopes somebody can help clarify the IOS ATT guidelines.

I have been reading and re-reading it over and over again and I can't seem to get a solid yes or no in regards to if my app need to apply this or not.

So a bit of background, I pushed out an update to our app a few weeks back, answered all the new privacy questions and a few days later I got an email saying that my app 'tracks' users and need to add the ATT.

This is not a huge deal but reading over the guidelines I'm not sure if it apply, simply because

1. We don't use a 3rd part API for our analytics (we have an in-house solution)
2. We don't sell the data
3. The data is not linked to any 3rd part vendors
4. We don't use any advertising ID etc ( we allow them to put banner ads in app but again, these are all tied to our own in-house analytics and are not monetized)

Our app is a business app the companies use, so in one respect they can see the analytics, however they are not selling that data, it's just to see how a user may have interacted in the app etc. (this is all in the privacy policy)

Now, maybe I answered the questions wrong on the app store, so it got flagged but I also don't want to go around the rules and have apps removed for being in violation...

I did some testing with the ATT framework and noticed the 'alert' specifically say that the app would like to share your data with 3rd party apps, again something we do not do..

So the TLDR is, do we need to worry about this OR is it only for app that track/sell data using 3rd party  API etc?

Comment: If you use the IDFA you need ATT. If you don't, you don't. The simplest approach is go through your code and ensure that it doesn't use the IDFA. Referencing the IDFA is what triggers the requirement for ATT during review. If you want to keep using the IDFA then you should add an appropriate use description string to your info.plist and request access via ATT

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for this. I know for sure we are not using IDFA. I got an email from iTunes that stated 'You’ve indicated that your apps collect data to track users or devices' So I think it may have triggered it based on my answer, I mean we do collect data for analytics but do not share that data or sell it.. So it sounds like we will be ok then to not add it if no IDFA.. Wish Apple would not be so ambiguous with thing.. that questionnaire is a bit misleading.

Comment: Re-reading [the guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/) it is also considered tracking if you link or share data. It sounds like you need to revise your privacy answers to indicate that you do not collect data to track users or devices; simply collecting analytics about use of a single app is not "tracking"; it is only tracking when you combine that data with activity elsewhere (another app, another device, another web site...)

Comment: See this is where I get a bit tripped up, and maybe thats due to semantics of the word track. Our app does 'Track' a user in app in the sense of analytics (user clicked on this section of the app etc) but it looks like apples uses the term 'track' in regards to tracking across other application so looking up x-product in one app will let another app your interested etc. That's something we don't do, it's really just for metrics of usage in-app not to sell etc. But how apple words it 'track' != 'track' unless is to a 3rd party?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Apple App Store policies are off topic.

Comment: How is it off-topic? It's affecting a developer's work and requires coding actions. I think this is an important topic.
I'm too affected with same issue. I have an app that I'm just adding new features to, and rejected for the same reason. They stated in their rejection that it's because we stated in App Store Connect that the app tracks user's info. So I need to know exactly what tracking is considered under ATT? And if just collecting user's info to authenticate him/her and allow auth-ed functionality is under ATT requirements.
A clear answer will help.

Comment: @MostafaAlBelliehy After doing more research on the topic, and to put it as simply as possible, as long as your app does not 'sell' the users data to third party's you should be ok. The wording they use is terribly confusing and us as developers never want to give IOS a reason to remove our app for being disingenuous. The key here is to answer yes to 'tracking' no to 'sharing' the data. We actually have a 'pattern' we follow when answering this because, as noted the wording they use is confusing at best.